# cocos2d running sequences in order on different targets

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

So, i have a basic game scenerario:

Some unit moves close to an enemy unit, shoots projectile and then enemy unit's life is adjusted. My problem is that I am not sure how to schedule these three events to run one after another. If all these actions were done on the same target, then this would be super easy, but there are two different targets.

What would be best approach to do this?

Code looks like this:

```
Unit* unit = [self getActiveUnit];
Unit* enemy = [self getEnemyInRange:unit];

CGpoint A = unit.sprite.position;
CGPoint B = [self getPositionClose:enemy for:unit];

CCSequence* unitMove = [self generateUnitMoveFrom:A to:B];

Projectile* proj = [self generateProjectile];
CCSequence* projMove = [self generateProjMoveFrom:A to:B];

CCSequence* attackDone = [self generateAttackDoneFor:unit enemy:enemy];

// This is the part that i don't know how to do
// Execute these in order and sequentially, not at the same time
[unit.sprite runAction:unitMove];
[proj.sprite runAction:projMove];
[proj.sprite runAction:removeSprite];
[self runAction:attackDone];
```

What is the best approach to do this? Even using CCActionManager it still seems fairly complicated because i think i would have to add an extra call back between all these actions to resume scheduled actions for the next target.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I marked James's answer as the right one because it was first and closest to what i was asking, although other solutions are valid and necessary. Wish I could mark multiple :(

Comment: Though still not fair to others that answered correctly, you could amend an existing answer to make it more complete. Or write your own that is an amalgamation of other answers and mark that as complete instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would attempt to use `CCSequence`

```
[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:
  [CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:unit.sprite selector:@selector(runAction:) object:unitMove],
  [CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:proj.sprite selector:@selector(runAction:) object:projMove],
  [CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:proj.sprite selector:@selector(runAction:) object:removeSprite],
  [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(attackDone)],
                     nil]];
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that CCCallFuncO is the action in this case, not the actual animation or whatever. All of these will be executed in sequence, but since they are just function calls they happen instantly. I hope that makes sense.

For example, in my case, yes the sprite starts to move, but split second later it is removed, because function call itself has no time out unlike the movement animation. So, I don't even see anything fly. :(

Comment: So, i added Justin's timeout solution between calls :)

Answer (score 2):

You may need this code for running Multiple `CCAction` ( **each action for a different CCNode/CCSprite/...** ) ; But starting All **in sequence** !

```
CCMoveBy *moveUpAction = CCMoveBy::create(0.5,ccp(0,400));
CCMoveBy *moveRightAction = CCMoveBy::create(1,ccp(300,0));
CCMoveBy *moveDownAction = CCMoveBy::create(1,ccp(0,-400));

CCTargetedAction *mm = CCTargetedAction::create(someNode_1,moveUpAction);
CCTargetedAction *rr = CCTargetedAction::create(someNode_2,moveRightAction);
CCTargetedAction *dd = CCTargetedAction::create(someNode_3,moveDownAction);

// Here we first run 'moveUpAction' on someNode_1.
// After finishing that Action we start 'moveRightAction' on someNode_2
// After finishing the Action, we start ...
CCSequence *targetedSeq = CCSequence::create(mm,rr,dd,NULL);
whateverNode->runAction(targetedSeq );
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with James. Plus you could add in a delay if there was some action you wanted to give a little more time to before the others are run...

> [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.5 ];

Comment: I used your solution with James's example :)

Answer (score 1):

you can create an array of your actions, then scedule some method to call them one by one. For example

```
- (void) playManyActionsOneByOne
{
    // create some actions and add them to the
    // mutable array m_actionsContainer

    [self runNextActionInArray];
}

- (void) runNexActionInArray
{
    if( [m_actionsContainer count > 0] )
    {
        id nextAction = [m_actionsContainer objectAtIndex:0];
        id callback = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(runNextActionInArray)];
        id sequence = [CCSequence actionOne: nextActon two: callback];
        [neededNode runAction: sequence];

        [m_actionsContainer removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }    
}
```

it will run actions one by one and you even can add actions to your array while other actions aren't done yet.

Comment: I think down the road i will have to come up with something like what you are suggesting. I am kinda taking the easy road while learning these things and prototyping:)