# How do I make an animation 2 wait for animation 1 to complete before executing, in Cocos2D, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone

In my program, when you tap the screen in the iOS Sim, cards are dealt out, using CCMoveTo.  The animation takes .4 seconds to complete.  Tap the screen again and the next set of cards is dealt.  This second animation takes .4 seconds also.  All I want to do is prohibit my program from dealing out that second set of cards before the first animation is complete.  Tried sleep() and, obviously, couldn't achieve the desired effect.  Also tried Cocos2D's CCDelayTime a few different ways and couldn't produce the desired result.  What's the easiest and/or most memory-efficient way to go about doing this?

EDIT:  @crackity_jones - Here's my HelloWorldLayer file and the category I created for CCSprite to allow movement:

HelloWorldLayer.h

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
#import "CCSprite+MoveActions.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"

    // globals
CCSprite *card1;
...
CCSprite *card9;

@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer {
    NSMutableArray *deck;
    ...
    int touchCount;
}

...

@end
```

HelloWorldLayer.m

```
...

-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touchCount++;
    [self nextRound];
}

// one method to handle all rounds dealt
-(void)nextRound {
    if (touchCount == 1) {
        [self removeAllCards];
        [deck shuffle];
        [self dealFirstRound];
    } else if (touchCount == 2) {
        [self dealSecondRound];
    } else if (touchCount == 3) {
        [self dealThirdRound];
    } else if (touchCount == 4) {
        [self dealFourthRound];
    touchCount = 0;
    }
}

-(NSMutableArray *)makeDeck {
    // create mutable array of 52 card sprites
}

-(void)dealFirstRound {
    ...
    // declare, define, add card objects to layer at start-point here
    …
    // the "moveToPositionX" methods contain the animation code
    [firstCard moveToPosition1];
    [secondCard …2];
    [third...3];
    [fourth...4];
    }

// Also methods for removing all rounds of cards
…
@end
```

CCSprite (MoveActions)

```
#import "CCSprite+MoveActions.h"
#define kCardTravelTime .1

@implementation CCSprite (MoveActions)

-(void)moveToPosition1 {
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    [self runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:kCardTravelTime
                                        position:CGPointMake(size.width/2 - card1.contentSize.width/4, card1.contentSize.height/2 + holeCard1.contentSize.height/5)]];
    CCDelayTime *waitTime = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:.4];
    [self runAction:waitTime];
}

-(void)moveToPosition2 {
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    CCDelayTime *delay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:.2];
    CCMoveTo *move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:kCardTravelTime
                                        position:CGPointMake(size.width/2 + card1.contentSize.width/4, card1.contentSize.height/2 + holeCard1.contentSize.height/5)];
    [self runAction:[CCSequence actions:delay, move, nil]];
}
// rest of the methods 3-9 look like the above, essentially

@end
```

Comment: Essentially, I want my ccTouchesEnded method to reject any screen-touches the user inputs until the first animation is done.  The way it's going now--which is not what I want--the user can tap the screen twice quickly and both animations will occur concurrently.

Comment: Add a flag called isDealing that is checked when a touch is received, if it is true then don't start a new deal action, if its not then start one. Set it to false at the end of your animation code with a [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:selector]

Comment: Tried what you said, Crackity (above), but I think I might've been missing the CCCallFunc portion of it.  Gonna give that a shot.

Comment: Showing more of the code you're using would make it easier to offer a solution.

Comment: if I understand right what do you want to achieve, look to my answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035114/cocos2d-running-sequences-in-order-on-different-targets/11036578#11036578

Answer (score 1):

You can try this! Use can insert some CCDelaytime action in CCSequence action if you need.

```
-(void)dealFirstRound {
    id card1Move = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        [firstCard moveToPosition1];
    }];
    id card2Move = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        [secondCard moveToPosition2];
    }];
    id card3Move = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        [thirdCard moveToPosition3];
    }];
    id card4Move = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        [fourthCard moveToPosition4];
    }];
    [self runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                     card1Move,
                     card2Move,
                     card3Move,
                     card4Move,
                     nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do a `CCSequence` like this:

```
[<<CCNode>> runAction:[[CCSequence actions:[deal hand],[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:.4],[deal 2nd hand].. ,nil]];
```

this will do the 1st action, delay for .4 s , do the 2nd action..and so on..you can add how many actions you want

Comment: I understand your example, skytz, but the only thing is both animations occur when the user touches the screen.  touch1 triggers animation1, touch2 triggers animation2.  That part, I got.  The only part I'm having difficulty with is making animation2 wait until animation1 is complete.  Like so:  touch the screen once and the card animation occurs.  While card animation is occurring, tap the screen nothing happens.  After card animation 1 is complete, tap the screen, THEN animation 2 occurs.  I hope I'm articulating this well enough.

Comment: well in that case..you could just deactivate all touches for .4 s (unless you need to touch somewhere meanwhile)